Ubuntu 22.04 kernel update 6.5->6.8: no boot, initramfs, busybox
I have a system with zentyal 8 based on ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS. The system works well with kernel 6.5.0-41-generic while if I install the latest hwe kernel 6.8.0-47-generic it fails to boot with the following error:
 Volume group "vgserver" not found
 Cannot process volume group vgserver 
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
 Volume group "vgserver" not found
 Cannot process volume group vgserver 
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common causes:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) 
ALERT! /dev/mapper/vgserver-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell! 

Busybox v1.30.1 (ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1 built in shell (ash))
(initramfs)

After installing the latest kernel I tried to run: update-initramfs -u -k. However, it have not solved the problem.
What can I do? Is there any way to have the latest kernel?
Thank you
